# on MVVMLight can I have 1 project for both WP7 and WP8

Tags: mvvm-light, windows-phone-8

I'm confused from the package of the latest MVVM Light V4.1 (4.1.24.0) as in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries 
there are different directories for WP7 and WP8.

My understanding was that the same app can work on WP7 and WP8, so I was not planning to have two different projects.

The question is how can I have a single project for both platforms?
Is it possible?
Which library should I link to the project?

thank you,
M

Answer (score 0):

Though WP7 application will run on WP8 and it's is quite possible to maintain a single project for both but quirk mode has some disadvantages.

Read about it here:-
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
and then decide.

IMO you should maintain two projects.